# Jenkinsfile: varibale not "parsed" inside SSH command

Tags: java, jenkins, ssh, build

I have a version of my artifact defined in the JenkinfFile which is resolved fine. I tested this with the output of the variable. However, it does not get parsed during an SSH command. What is the right syntax ?

```
        version = sh (
        script: './gradlew -q printVersion',
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()

    echo "$version" 

    sshPut remote: remote, from: 'build/libs/core-\${version}-all.jar', into: '/opt/microservices/core.jar'
```

Output:

1.0.6
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /jenkins/workspace/core/build/libs/core-${version}-all.jar does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for String interpolation in Groovy:-

```
sshPut remote: remote, from: "build/libs/core-${version}-all.jar", into: '/opt/microservices/core.jar'
```

This is why your `echo` statement is working fine, but your `sshPut` is not.

See: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation

Comment: The sollution does not work. Same problem

Comment: @Jacob remove the backslash, you've escaped the $ by accident.

Comment: Got it. Thank you